# Making the camera permission required by the library as not required

Tags: android, permissions, android-camera

In my app i include a library that request camera. This limits my application for devices without camera and i need it specifically for a device with scanner but no camera. So i want to make the camera permission as not required in my app. How can i do this.

I added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
```

in my apps manifest. Is that enough?

Or should i add tools:node="remove" or tools:node="replace" in my app like as below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" tools:node="replace" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's enough. You set it to be a non-required feature, so it's non-required.

Just because you use the CAMERA permission doesn't mean the device has to have a camera. You could put in:

```
<uses-permission android:name="hue.com.derp" />
```

And it wouldn't restrict your compatibility base at all. If the host device doesn't recognize a permission, it ignores it.

The `tools` namespace has zero effect on runtime. It's simply for you to provide the IDE with a sample of what might happen during runtime, so it can update previews and the like.

Comment: I have edited my question. Added more clarification to "is that enough" part

Comment: the device doesnt restrict but google play will. So its for allowing the device with no camera also to install from google play

Comment: No it won't. Google Play will not prevent a device from installing an app if it requests a permission that device doesn't use.

Comment: u mean if i dont add <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" /> and still i can install from google play on a device with no camera

Comment: Yes, because you put in the `required="false"`. It's not required, so Google Play isn't going to require it.

Comment: my question was if i DONT add required = false , will it restrict. because from ur comments i read it as it will not restrict, just ignore

Comment: If you don't add the entire `uses-feature` blocks, Google Play won't restrict either.

Comment: It DOES filter s

Comment: I'm not going to just keep repeating the same thing to you over and over. You can test it yourself if you don't believe me

Answer (score 0):

I would say check the device type first if it has camera & 6.0+ then you need to ask for permission other wise just run your code normal